# Scrapy not entering into parse method

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having a problem with Scrapy, for some reason it is not entering my parse method, and i have no idea why could that be. I have tried different options without success.

This is how my code looks now. Specifically, there is are two print statements, and the one in the parse() method is not being called.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from comments.items import CustomerReview
import re

class AppidSpider(BaseSpider):

  name = "appid"
    allowed_domains = ["itunes.apple.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8"
    ]

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='parse')]
    print "---> THIS IS TEST 1"

    def parse(self, response):
        print " ----> THIS IS TEST 2"
        # ... More code afterwards
```

And this is the output. As you can see TEST 2 is never printed.

```
$ scrapy crawl appid
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: comments)
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
---> THIS IS TEST 1
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: FilterWordsPipeline
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [appid] INFO: Spider opened
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [appid] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [appid] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8> (referer: None)
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [appid] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [appid] INFO: Dumping spider stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 222,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 9927,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 13, 41, 2, 694678),
         'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 13, 41, 2, 604025)}
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [appid] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2012-07-05 13:41:02+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping global stats:
        {'memusage/max': 95318016, 'memusage/startup': 95318016}
```

Comment: If you are using Rules, you should inherit from CrawlSpider, not BaseSpider and choose a different name (not 'parse') for the parse method.

Comment: Thanks, this could explain a secondary issue I am facing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you pass parse as a string? Try `callback=self.parse` instead.

Comment: Thanks. When I put self.parse I get the error
    NameError: name 'self' is not defined
Could that be related? Maybe there is an issue with indenting or something?

Comment: Probably. The indentation of the excerpt doesn't make sense at all, I was guessing both the call and the parse method belong to the class. Do they?

Comment: Well, once I asked that question I tried. No idea what it was but it was a problem with indentation. I re'indented the whole script and it worked well now. Looks like it originally was to me though :)

Answer (score 2):

As Creshal said you in callback you need to use call some method but not parse, some other custom method of yours.

But in this case it shouldn't be the problem cause you actually don't have any rules to follow, so it's not important.

I tried your code and it works fine for me, it prints out both messages.

Comment: Points for helping. This was not the answer, but it led me to the answer the fact that it worked for you and not me.